# how to print barcode from a barcode label printer in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, barcode

I Have a button and a Textbox ,when a user click on that button the number entered in the textbox should be printed from barcode printer (citizen printer) in a barcode format to the barcode label paper.

How can i do this.??

I did some RND ,i have created a bat file. In that file, i have written code as

```
copy c:/desktop/myfolder/textfile.txt b\ citizen
```

Is my approach correct ??? ,is there any different techniq to print barcode through barcode label printer.

Please help,I am not able to print.

Answer (score 0):

To be successful in your approach, your asp.net script would need to:

1. write the field entry to the textfile.txt file
2. trigger the launch of the batch file to send textfile.txt to the printer port

This is assuming:

1. you set up the printer correctly - to print from a command prompt like your `COPY` command suggests, you'll need to set up the printer as a share and then map to a command-line-recognizable port ( `NET USE LPT2 \\COMPUTER\PRINTER` )
2. your asp.net script wrote textfile.txt in a format that the printer can understand

The actual command in the batch file to copy textfile.txt would be:

```
copy /B c:\desktop\myfolder\textfile.txt LPT2
```

Change the paths and ports to the ones on your system. If this is set up in a server environment, you'll need to make sure permissions are correct as well so that the asp.net script can launch a batch file..